# Is it possible in Nuxt.js to have multiple route parameters with same level hierarchy?

Tags: vue-router, nuxt.js

Is it possible in Nuxt.js to have multiple route parameters with same level hierarchy?
For instance:

```
- entry
-- _id.vue
-- _slug.vue
- index.js
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**No**, it's not possible.

But you can use a simple workaround.

#### Case 1

You need both `_id` and `_slug` in the same route. Then you can simply nest them. So that your route will look like this: `entry/_id/_slug`. And your files would look like this:

```
entry/
--| _id/
-----| index.vue //this one is for _id
-----| _slug/
--------| index.vue //this one is for _slug
```

Also you can swap `_id` with `_slug` if it fits your needs better.

#### Case 2

You need two different routes: `entry/id/_id` and `entry/slug/_slug`. In this case your files would look like this:

```
entry/
--| id/
-----| _id.vue
--| slug/
-----| _slug.vue
```

Answer (score 0):

With Nuxt3, for an URL like this `mywebsite.com/param1/param2/param3`, you need this structure:

```
pages
└── [param1]
    └── [param2]
        └── [param3].vue
```

And to show it in the console, put this in `[param3].vue`

```
<script setup>
import { useRoute } from "vue-router";
const route = useRoute();
console.log(route.params);
</script>
```

ref. https://nuxt.com/docs/guide/directory-structure/pages#nested-routes